# using quantile() in r to find value

Tags: r

Using the `quantile()` function in a class here is my code so far:

```
p <- seq(.01,.99,.01)

sample_quantiles <- quantile(act_scores, p)
```

I am trying to find the quantile associated with the value "26" in the data set, as opposed to the inverse:

```
sample_quantiles[26]
```

Comment: For future questions, please make sure that you format the code correctly. You can find a guideline [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Please provide the data for the variable `act_scores`. The Error you get would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ecdf` for this:

```
ecdf(act_scores)(26)
```